# Secret server protocol keeping software free

Tags: c, protocols, network-protocols

I am currently learning about basic networking in C, and I'm interested in an "obscure" part of Internet: secret protocols.

Let's say I develop a multiplayer online game. I would design my own protocol for packing and unpacking data, so both the client and the server can send, receive and parse information properly (e.g.: positional packets, casting spells... and so on). Of course, I don't want that protocol to be in the public domain, because anyone that wants to make "bad things" in my server will be able to do them. But I want to keep my project free software.

What should I do, then? Can you tell me about how to keep my hypothetic project open source, without making it insecure?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

Comment: @ouah, I'd upvote it as an answer too (though I haven't read the page you refer to).

Comment: Is there anything limiting you from securing the access to the server via a user/pass mechanism. A proprietary protocol can be reverse engineered.

Comment: @Ifthikhan Well, not. I can create an 'account' structure (or class, or whatever) describing an account, and "linking" it to an IP address when an user open his/her account. Although some requests (for example, a client asking the server its local time) don't need to be validated.

Comment: @shura-astrozero You can have calls (RPC or API endpoints) which are public and some which require authentication. In terms of building such a system it is not advisable to link it to an ip. Rather it should be along the lines where you provide an avenue for the user to register for your game prior to downloading the client or on the client itself. Thereafter before the user starts playing the game he would login and then continue the game.

Answer (score 6):

Impossible - if you're providing the source code, you're also providing the implementation of the protocol. You cannot secure something which has its doors wide open. Instead, you focus on securing ACCESS to the server-side stuff.

e.g. you're trying to keep people from knowing your application speaks english, when you should be focusing on filtering english speakers by their ID badges.

Comment: @PawełDziepak I thought the same. What about "decompilation"? All about the protocol stuff would go in a static library, and code will be copied into, let's say, the client executable. So everyone (not me) which has some advanced knowledge can get through compiled code. (sorry, Paul wrote a comment that it's not available now)

Answer (score 3):

You could use encryption and not include the client key in the open source. However, since you must include it in the client it can rather easily be hacked. It will always be possible to hack your server, but in many cases you can keep control and validation in the server. For example the server can keep track on ho many pieces of gold you are carrying and the client can tell the server to buy a new tool for X gold pieces. The server can easily verify the transaction and keep the inventory. The same goes for movement: The server knows where the clients are and where they can go. Still, this does not prevents robots though.

Comment: I prefer not doing so, because, as you pointed out, that can easily be hacked. The protocol should define data encapsulation, padding, and of course, data encryption (as an "external shield"). If people know the protocol, and they have the file that contains the key, it would be quiet easy to decrypt messages. Thanks in any case

Comment: Well, as I said don't supply the key. If I remember correctly android will use encrypted application packages for paid apps. Using that, will make it much harder to get the key, and if the key leaks it is easy to invalidate it. Thus, it depends on which system you are targeting. Anyway, the most important part is that the server should verify the commands according to my answer.

Comment: I'm targeting for desktop computers (as well as laptops,... etc). Sorry for misunderstanding you - I thought you say "... you must include it in the client ...". After your answers, I get that validation is the idea, so I will take paper and that head I got and think about all what you've said. Thanks!